# Protect outbound IP

Tags: security

What do you suggest as the best way to protect your web servers IP address for outgoing requests? I'm already using Cloudflare for inbound requests but if my web server (nodejs) is making outbound connections for sending webhooks or something, I would prefer not to expose my origins IP. I have a firewall set up to prevent any connections inbound not coming from Cloudflare but I don't want my IP to expose where I'm hosted only to have my datacenter receive a DDoS.

There actually aren't any good articles I can find anywhere regarding protecting your IP with outbound connections.

Two thoughts:

1) Set up a second datacenter containing proxy servers and route outbound web server traffic through the proxy servers.

2) Set up a webhook queue, send webhooks to the queue and have servers in a 2nd datacenter work the queue.

Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I have worked at my company with a number of models over the years, including both ones that you listed. We started out using a queue that were available to web hook processors on remote data centers, but we transitioned over to a model that had less emphasis on queues, and instead simplified it; an originating server chooses one of the available notification/web hook senders, that in turns calls the web hook subscriber. The sender also takes care of buffering, resending, alerting and aging of messages.

For the purpose of protecting your IP address, it depends on a number of variables. In our case, we acquire additional IP address ranges for the senders, but you can achieve your goal by having the proxy hosted on AWS or similar.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want to do this?  Your inbound requests are already dropped if they aren't from cloudflare.

Comment: So they don't know where you are hosted so they can attack the datacenter.

Comment: But if you route it through another data center, can't they attack that one?

Comment: Absolutely. But then the only thing that would be affected would be your outbound webhooks/connections, not your website itself.